# Unexpected results from typename

Tags: vba, ms-word, typename

I am getting some unexpected results from typename and am stumped.  Hopefully some can point me in the right direction.

```
Private Sub T()
    Dim d As Word.Document
    Dim s As String
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim o As Object

    Set d = ActiveDocument
    s = "X"
    Set c = New Collection

    Debug.Print "d is a " & TypeName(d)
    Debug.Print "s is a " & TypeName(s)
    Debug.Print "c is a " & TypeName(c)

    c.Add (d)
    c.Add (s)
    For i = 1 To c.count
        Debug.Print "Item " & i & " of the collection is a " & " " & TypeName(c.Item(i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

From which I get the following output:

```
d is a Document
s is a String
c is a Collection
Item 1 of the collection is a String
Item 2 of the collection is a String
```

What I expected to get was:

```
d is a Document
s is a String
c is a Collection
Item 1 of the collection is a Document
Item 2 of the collection is a String
```

Any ideas why I get "String" instead of "Document" for the first item in the collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c.Add (d)
```

is not the same as

```
c.Add d
```

In the first, by wrapping `d` in parentheses you're causing it to be *evaluated as an expression* and the result of that expression (in this case a String) gets added to the collection. In the second, the `d` object itself is added.

Try comparing directly in the Immediate window:

```
? TypeName(ActiveDocument)       '>> Document
```

and

```
? TypeName( (ActiveDocument) )   '>> String
```

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know if I ever would have figured that out.  Couldn't even count how many times I head the help and kept coming up with the same thing every time.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. One way to flag these types of issues is to watch out for when the VBEditor adds or preserves a space between a keyword (eg. a method name such as Add) and an opening parenthesis - if the parenthesis is required for the method call there will be no space there (and the editor will remove it if you put one...)