# ms access - vba: Compile Error: expected: =

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subroutine as below

```
Public Sub updateStagesTable(sName As String, percentageValue As Double)
    stageName = "'" & sName & "'"
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO StagesT ([Stage Name], [Stage Value In Percentage]) VALUES (" & stageName & "," & percentageValue & ");"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
End Sub
```

and I call it from another subroutine as below

```
economy = 3.53
updateStagesTable ("Economy", economy)
```

But I get this compile error

```
Compile Error: expected: =
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
updateStagesTable ("Economy", economy)
```

should be

```
updateStagesTable "Economy", economy
```

with no parentheses

See related: [Unexpected results from typename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186853/unexpected-results-from-typename/22188933#22188933)

Comment: Wow, this is so destabilizing for any developer coming from sane languages!

Comment: It is what it is - it's maybe just different from what you're used to.  It's not an issue of sane or not sane.

Answer (score 27):

I have never liked this peculiarity of VB so I always use the alternate CALL syntax, in your case this would be:

```
Call updateStagesTable("Economy", economy)
```

which does allow the parentheses that all other languages expect

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an area of confusion!

For one thing, wrapping the input argument in parentheses [*seems* to work for some subroutine calls](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-compile-error-expect-in-sub-call/a47c752f-3034-41a6-a77c-b3ddaa34b24c).  And, furthermore, the tooltips in the VBA Editor mirror the statement defining the procedure, which includes parentheses!

So what is behind the confusion?  Below is some basic code to explore this.

```
' Simple subroutine with two input arguments.
Sub twoInputs(in1, in2)
    Debug.Print in1 & " eats "; in2 & "!"
End Sub

' Simple subroutine with one input argument.
Sub oneInput(in1)
    Debug.Print in1 & " eats pizza!"
End Sub

' Routine to test various syntaxes for calling subroutines.
Sub subCallingTest()
    'twoInputs("Cat", "fish")       'FAILS.  Parentheses cannot be ignored here.  
    twoInputs "Cat", "fish"         'Works.
    twoInputs ("Cat"), ("fish")     'Works, but only because parentheses can be ignored here!
    Call twoInputs("Cat", "fish")   'Works.
    'Call twoInputs "Cat", "fish"   'FAILS.  Parentheses are required here.  
    
    oneInput "Daughter"         'Works.
    oneInput ("Daughter")       'Works, but only because parentheses can be ignored here!
    Call oneInput("Daughter")   'Works.
    'Call oneInput "Daughter"   'FAILS.  Parentheses are required here.  
End Sub
```

It turns out that the parentheses are tolerated for a single input argument *if* the procedure/code only cares about the *value* of the inputs (see counter-example at the end), because **they can be ignored** in the same way as they can be when they are wrapped around individual numbers — but not when they are wrapped around several numbers.

```
debug.print 1 + 2 * 10      ' Answer is 21.
debug.print (1) + (2) * 10  ' Answer is 21.
debug.print (1 + 2) * 10    ' Answer is 30.
```

There is one very subtle clue as to when the parentheses are expected, which is in the spacing.  Notice that the Editor inserts a space after the procedure's name in `oneInput ("Daughter")`, but not in `Call oneInput("Daughter")`.

—DIV

**P.S.** If a procedure has *no arguments* at all, then parentheses are not used to invoke it (neither with nor without the `call` statement).

**P.P.S.** A subroutine can be guaranteed to only care about the values of the input arguments if the inputs are explicitly marked as `ByVal` in the defining `Sub` statement.  In my examples above there is no explicit designation of the input arguments, so [the arguments have defaulted to `ByRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sub-statement#syntax);  however, it is apparent from the above examples that the performance will nevertheless be unaffected.  A simple *counter-example* would be as follows.

```
Sub oneInputMod(in1)
    in1 = UCase(in1)
    Debug.Print in1 & " eats pizza!"
End Sub

Sub subCallingTestMod()
    person = "everyone"         ' Set a local variable's value.
    oneInputMod person          ' Works.
    Debug.Print person          ' Output is "EVERYONE", as nominally intended.
    
    person = "everyone"         ' Reset a local variable's value.
    oneInputMod (person)        ' Seems to work, judging by immediately visible output (which was not affected by the parentheses).
    Debug.Print person          ' Output is "everyone", which is nominally unintended.
    
    person = "everyone"         ' Reset a local variable's value.
    Call oneInputMod(person)    ' Works.
    Debug.Print person          ' Output is "EVERYONE", as nominally intended.
End Sub
```

Comment: Careful! It is wrong to say that in the case of calling a sub like this: `ExampleSub (Argument)` parenthesis can be ignored! This is not at all the case, the parenthesis in this case force passing the argument `ByVal`. Even if the sub `ExampleSub` explicitly takes its arguments `ByRef`, calling it like this `ExampleSub (Argument)` will force `ByVal`! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15519085/12287457) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, My initial focus was on elucidating why parentheses sometimes 'seem' to work.  However, it's a fair point that even parentheses that wrap individual inputs cannot be ignored *generally* (although it was safe in my simple original examples).  I have added a counter-example to illustrate that concretely.

Comment: "Ignore" or "tolerate" parentheses is a wrong approach in my opinion. One should always use parentheses deliberately - use `Call` if you want to put them around single arguments. Also `Global` is kinda deprecated and should be `Public`.

Comment: Andre, please understand that I am not recommending to use redundant parentheses.  I am endeavouring to explain why sometimes they *seem to work*, and why those specific occasions *cannot* be generalised to all situations.