# VBA - IsObject(myobject) returns True, however getting "object required" error

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I am attempting to create a bridge between VBA UserForm and a webbrowser control on the form. I don't like the limitations of VBA to query the HTML document or implement changes on the fly and would like to use Javascript instead.

So far I have tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim head As HTMLGenericElement
Dim scriptEl As HTMLGenericElement
Dim element As IHTMLScriptElement

Set head = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")(0)
Set scriptEl = WebBrowser1.Document.createElement("script")

        scriptEl.Text = "function sayHello() { alert('hello') }"

        head.appendChild (scriptEl)
        WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript ("sayHello")
End Sub
```

I get the error 424 - object required at the "head.appendChild" line.

I have used IsObject() on both head, and scriptEl, both return true. So I totally confused!

If anyone could provide some guidance on what is happening that would be fantastic, or how to adapt what I have so far to carry scripts through the bridge like:

```
 WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript ("my javascript code that I wish to run here")
```

Comment: So scriptel is working? It is set?

Comment: Hey, I have used MsgBox to dsiaply scriptel.Text, and it displays the text

Comment: how about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38104423/create-brand-new-xml-node-to-append-as-child-to-other-node

Comment: Hi Gene, yes I think it may be related, somehow thinking the declarations are maybe of the wrong type? Unsure so far, just trying to test all of the different types..

Comment: remove the parenthesesfrom around `scriptEl`.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186853/unexpected-results-from-typename/22188933#22188933

Comment: Hi Tim, nailed it. submit an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
head.appendChild (scriptEl)
```

Here the parentheses around `scriptEl` are causing it to be evaluated as an expression (and the result of that evaluation is likely a non-object type.

```
head.appendChild scriptEl
```

Should work fine.