# Why does appendChild give me run-time error 438 (Object doesn't support this property or method)?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, dom, ms-access-2007

I'm editing an XML document with VBA code.  I want to build up a new, nested set of elements and then use replaceChild to substitute this portion of XML for a similar, existing element.  I am getting run-time error 438 when trying to insert a text node into my first new element.

I copied this approach from a tutorial example I found online so expected it to work without a hitch.

I'm trying to build up this section of XML:

```
<ConnectionProperties>
<DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider> 
</ConnectionProperties>
```

To build up the elements:

```
Dim NewElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim NewNodeElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim NewNodeText As MSXML2.IXMLDOMText

Set NewElement = xmlDoc.createNode(1, "ConnectionProperties", xmlNameSpace)

Set NewNodeElement = xmlDoc.createNode(1, "DataProvider", xmlNameSpace)
Set NewNodeText = xmlDoc.createTextNode("SQL")

NewNodeElement.appendChild (NewNodeText)    <--- Get run-time error 438 here

NewElement.appendChild (NewNodeElement)
```

I get the run-time error attempting to insert the text value "SQL" into the DataProvider tag.

I expected the text to be inserted into the element but I get a run-time error instead.

Comment: `NewNodeElement.appendChild  NewNodeText` with no parentheses.  Adding parentheses causes an item to be *evaluated* - the result of that may be different from the enclosed item.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186853/unexpected-results-from-typename/22188933#22188933